# Escape spaces in grep

Tags: grep

```
tail /mnt/mysqld_log/mysql_error_log.err  | grep -e `date +'%y%m%d' --date='4 hour ago'` | more

120824 11:25:06 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Table '.zone_assoc' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
120824 18:03:23 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '.ad_zone_assoc.MYI'; try to repair it
120824 18:08:38 [ERROR] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Incorrect key file for table '.ad_zone_assoc.MYI'; try to repair it
```

The above works as expected and shows the results for today's date. But the following does not work.

```
tail /mnt/mysqld_log/mysql_error_log.err  | grep -e `date +'%y%m%d %k' --date='4 hour ago'` | more

grep: 18: No such file or directory
```

I tried to escape the space and that did not work as well.

```
tail /mnt/mysqld_log/mysql_error_log.err  | grep -e `date +'%y%m%d\ %k' --date='4 hour ago'` | more

grep: Trailing backslash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the `date` command with quotes:

```
tail /mnt/mysqld_log/mysql_error_log.err  | grep -e "`date +'%y%m%d %k' --date='4 hour ago'`" | more
```

The space is being interpreted as the file you are trying to read from, by encasing it in quotes, this will not happen.

Comment: What is the exact cron command?  You might need to put it in a wrapper script to work as expected, but send me the cron and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: The cron entry is working after escaping the % sign. Thanks for the quick help.